# How can I sort, find duplicates in one column and delete them together with their match in another column?

Tags: unix

I have a really big file with this information

```
7-92383888 rs10
7-6013153 rs10000
12-126890980 rs1000000
4-57561647 rs10000003
4-85161558 rs10000005 
4-172776204 rs10000008
4-71048953 rs10000009 
2-50711642 rs1000001
```

The first column is the chromosome number and the base pair position and the second column is the SNP which can be found in this specific area. In the first column there are some duplicates, but not in the second one. How can I sort column 1, find duplicates and then delete the entire row? So, delete the duplicate of column 1 and at the same time their matching value in column 2. Also, while sorting I dont want the match between column 1 and column 2 to change.

I read previous posts and I know that I have to use sort and uniq command but I dont know how.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`sort` has `-u' flag for that.

```
sort -uk 1
```

Here's an example:

```
$ echo -e 'b 1\na 2\nb 1\na 2' | sort -uk 1
a 2
b 1
```

Comment: Thank you! Does this command include also the delete option? and where should I write the name of the file?

Comment: `-u` stands for 'unique', that is, each sorting key (here column 1 value) appears at most once in the output. The name of the file can go anywhere, say, after options. If you want to write the result to another file, redirect output. So, to sort the contents of `input.txt` and write the results to `output.txt`, run `sort -uk 1 input.txt >output.txt`.